# Freeze when writing ffmpeg execution result to io.Pipe

Tags: go, ffmpeg, pipe

I am writing a wrapper to work with `exec.Cmd` to work with `io.Pipe`. The wrapper is intended to simplify work with the file system, I want to convert a video, write the result of the conversion to `io.Pipe`, read it in the goroutine and transfer it to make a preview of the new converted file. For this purpose I use `FFmpeg`. But I've encountered a problem, when I start the test the execution just hangs and I can't get any result, but there are no errors, everything just hangs.

CmdRunner source code

```golang
type CmdRunner struct {
    commander Commander
    StdIn io.ReadCloser
    StdoutWriter io.WriteCloser
    StdErrWriter io.Writer
}

func (c *CmdRunner) RunByPipe(ctx context.Context) error {
    //done := make(chan error)
    name, args := c.commander.Command()
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, name, args...)

    if c.StdIn != nil {
        fmt.Print("RunByPipe STDIN\n")
        cmd.Stdin = c.StdIn
    }

    if c.StdoutWriter != nil {
        fmt.Print("RunByPipe STDOUT\n")
        cmd.Stdout = c.StdoutWriter
    }

    stderr := bytes.Buffer{}
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if stderr.String() != "" {
        return fmt.Errorf("want empty stderr, but got %s", stderr.String())
    }

    return nil
}
```

Unit test code

```golang
type TestCommander struct {
    name string
    args []string
}

func (c *TestCommander) SetCommand(name string, args []string) {
    c.name = name
    c.args = args
}

func (c *TestCommander) Command() (string, []string) {
    return c.name, c.args
}

func TestConvert(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    filePath := "testdata/input_mp4.mp4"
    data, err := convertFile(filePath, ctx)
    outFile := "testdata/output_mp4.mp4"
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("ERR: ", err, "\n")
    }

    os.WriteFile(outFile, data, 0644)

}

func convertFile(filePath string, ctx context.Context) (bytes []byte, err error) {
    // Create a CmdRunner instance with your custom Commander.
    runner := &CmdRunner{}
    commander := &TestCommander{}
    args := []string{
        "-nostats",
        "-i", filePath,
        "-y",
        "-loglevel", "0",
        "-filter:v", "fps=30, crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2",
        "-c:v", "libx264",
        "-c:a", "aac",
        "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
        "-movflags", "frag_keyframe+faststart",
        "-bufsize", "24M",
        "-maxrate", "12M",
        "-f", "mp4",
        "pipe:1",
    }

    commander.SetCommand("ffmpeg", args)
    runner.SetCommander(commander)
    outputPipeReader, outputPipeWriter := io.Pipe()
    runner.SetStdOutWriter(outputPipeWriter)

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer outputPipeReader.Close()
        defer wg.Done()

        // Read data from output pipe
        bytes, err = io.ReadAll(outputPipeReader)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print("\nReadAll err: ", err, "\n")
        }
    }()

    err = runner.RunByPipe(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("\nRunByPipe err: ", err, "\n")
        return
    }

    wg.Wait()

    return
}
```

I can't find a clue as to what might have gone wrong.
P.S: But if I remove `if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil { return err }` Then the problem goes away, but there will be no data, because nothing is written to `io.Pipe`.Why?

Comment: `io.Pipe` does not create an os pipe, it's just Go structures.

Comment: io.ReadAll(outputPipeReader) blocks forever because outputPipeWriter is not closed.  Use os.Pipe instead of io.Pipe to reduce the number of goroutines created by cmd.Start (this change does not fix the problem mentioned in my first sentence).

Comment: @CeriseLimón - Thank you so much for your comment. It has helped me a lot. Post it as a reply and I will mark it as correct. I have finalized the ffmpeg library and I have a working example https://go.dev/play/p/rYs72oGUky7. Please add it to your reply so it will be visible in case it helps someone else. Thanks again

Comment: @alex I wrote a comment because I am too lazy to determine all the details for a proper answer.  Please write an answer with your learnings.